# Mage-messages are not working in magento 2 due to cookie SameSite:None

Tags: magento2.3.4

I have faced some problems with mage messages. Actually, they are working fine before when i have not done anything on the server. But after adding below line =>

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None
```

All mage-messages are not working. I know this is not a Magento relevant question but somehow I am very curious about & want to know why these messages stop. If I removed set-cookie same-site=none from the server then it will work fine.

**If someone faces the same problem please let me know.**

Add i don't want to remove `Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None`
because the latest browser update like Chrome treats cookies with no Same site value as SameSite = Lax. And it disables 3rd party modules using the cookies. So it is important to add any cross-site cookies to SameSite=None and label them as secure.

Comment: mage-messages is a client side frontend JS cookie, the header setting will have no affect on it.